# Compile Vivado IP-generated Librarys in "<proj>.ip_user_files" for ModelSim on Win7

Tags: vhdl, modelsim, vivado

thanks for reading my question.

If i generate a component with the "IP Catalog" in Vivado (2016.2), Vivado creates the following Folder(s) in my Project (I generated a counter for this example):

```
<proj>/ip_user_files/ip/c_counter_binary/c_counter_binary_0.veo
                                        /c_counter_binary_0.vho
                                        /c_counter_binary_0_stub.v
                                        /c_counter_binary_0_stub.vhdl

<proj>/ip_user_files/ipstatic/c_addsub_v12_0_9/hdl/c_addsub_v12_0.vhd
                                                  /c_addsub_v12_0_vh_rfs.vhd
                             /...(and a few more)

<proj>/ip_user_files/sim_scripts/c_counter_binary_0/modelsim/compile.do
                                                            /c_counter_binary_0.sh
                                                            /simulate.do
                                                            /wave.do

(I think the rest is irrelevant for my question)
```

I want to simulate the counter in ModelSim. So I think I have to run the "c_counter_binary_0.sh" to generate the necessary Simulation Librarys for ModelSim.

Whats a good way to compile these Librarys using Windows 7?

I'm trying to simulate the counter in ModelSim for a few days now, but I really have no idea left what I can try next.

Since it's a common think to do (isn't it?), i can't understand why I wasn't able to find any documentation.

---

Things I've tried:

---

Run c_counter_binary_0.sh with the ModelSim Transcript Console:

```
do c_counter_binary_0.sh
# ** Error: invalid command name "﻿#!/bin/bash"
```

---

Run the file compile.do in ModelSim Transcript Console:

```
do compile.do
# ** Warning: (vlib-34) Library already exists at "work".
# 
# Model Technology ModelSim PE vmap 10.4a Lib Mapping Utility 2015.03 Apr  7 2015
# vmap -modelsim_quiet xbip_utils_v3_0_6 msim/xbip_utils_v3_0_6 
# Modifying C:/Xilinx/wkdir/lab_counter/lab_counter.ip_user_files/sim_scripts/c_counter_binary_0/modelsim/lab_counter.mpf
# Model Technology ModelSim PE vmap 10.4a Lib Mapping Utility 2015.03 Apr  7 2015
# vmap -modelsim_quiet c_reg_fd_v12_0_2 msim/c_reg_fd_v12_0_2 
# Modifying C:/Xilinx/wkdir/lab_counter/lab_counter.ip_user_files/sim_scripts/c_counter_binary_0/modelsim/lab_counter.mpf

(...and so on...)

# Model Technology ModelSim PE Student Edition vcom 10.4a Compiler 2015.03 Apr  7 2015
# Start time: 00:59:17 on Oct 31,2016
# vcom -reportprogress 300 -work xbip_utils_v3_0_6 -64 -93 ../../../ipstatic/xbip_utils_v3_0_6/hdl/xbip_utils_v3_0_vh_rfs.vhd 
# -- Loading package STANDARD
# End time: 00:59:18 on Oct 31,2016, Elapsed time: 0:00:01
# Errors: 0, Warnings: 1
# ** Warning: (vcom-159) Mode option -64 is not supported in this context and will be ignored.
# 

(...and so on...all with no error...)

# 
# Model Technology ModelSim PE Student Edition vcom 10.4a Compiler 2015.03 Apr  7 2015
# Start time: 00:59:28 on Oct 31,2016
# vcom -reportprogress 300 -work xil_defaultlib -64 -93 ../../../../lab_counter.srcs/sources_1/ip/c_counter_binary_0/sim/c_counter_binary_0.vhd 
# -- Loading package STANDARD
# -- Loading package TEXTIO
# -- Loading package std_logic_1164
# -- Loading package NUMERIC_STD
# -- Compiling entity c_counter_binary_0
# -- Compiling architecture c_counter_binary_0_arch of c_counter_binary_0
# End time: 00:59:29 on Oct 31,2016, Elapsed time: 0:00:01
# Errors: 0, Warnings: 1
```

But I end up with empty librarys except:

xil_defaultlib --> [Entity]c_counter_binary_0 --> [Architecture]c_counter_binary_0_arch

If i try to run the Simulation with the generated Librarys:

```
vsim work.top_tb
# vsim 
# Start time: 01:08:10 on Oct 31,2016
# Loading std.standard
# Loading std.textio(body)
# Loading ieee.std_logic_1164(body)
# Loading work.top_tb(tb)
# Loading work.top(rtl)
# Loading ieee.numeric_std(body)
# Loading work.c_counter_binary_0(c_counter_binary_0_arch)
# Loading ieee.std_logic_arith(body)
# Loading ieee.std_logic_unsigned(body)
# Loading unisim.muxcy(muxcy_v)
# Loading unisim.xorcy(xorcy_v)
# ** Fatal: Attempting to load -nodebug design unit.
#  Nodebug designs are not supported.
# 
#    Time: 0 ns  Iteration: 0  Instance: /top_tb File: C:/Xilinx/wkdir/lab_counter/lab_counter.srcs/sim_1/imports/vhdl/tb_top.vhd Line: UNKNOWN
# FATAL ERROR while loading design
# Error loading design
```

---

Installed Cygwin and run c_counter_binary_0.sh

```
$ ./c_counter_binary_0.sh
./c_counter_binary_0.sh: line 1: uFEFF#!/bin/bash: No such file or directory
./c_counter_binary_0.sh: line 32: $'\r': command not found
./c_counter_binary_0.sh: line 33: $'\r': command not found
c_counter_binary_0.sh - Script generated by export_simulation (Vivado v2016.2 (64-bit)-id)

./c_counter_binary_0.sh: line 36: $'\r': command not found
./c_counter_binary_0.sh: line 38: syntax error near unexpected token `$'\r''
'/c_counter_binary_0.sh: line 38: `run()
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the student version is simply not able to load protected devices...

A friend of mine who is really into FPGAs took a look at my library mappings etc. and everything was ok... So he tested the design with a full Modelsim License...

ModelSim PE Student Edition:

```
...
# Loading unisim.xorcy(xorcy_v)
# ** Fatal: Attempting to load -nodebug design unit.
#  Nodebug designs are not supported.
# 
...
```

Modelsim with a full-license key:

```
...
# Loading unisim.xorcy(xorcy_v)
# ** Warning: (vsim-8684) No drivers exist on out port /top_tb
/DUT/c_counter_binary_0_1/U0/<protected>/<protected>/<protected>
/<protected>, and its initial value is not used.
# 
...
```